# how to load plist data into array in IOS property list

Tags: ios

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initwithContentOfFile:path];

    NSArray *textData=[NSArray new];

textData = [dict objectForkey:@"TableData"];
```

textData is my array name,
recipes is `plist` name
after excuting my text data is being empty...
where is the mistake.

Comment: what you want exactly array or dictionary?

Comment: check your plist name,is should `recipes.plist`.

Comment: Have you tried specifing the type in lowercase?

Comment: array. when i excuted ,my table view is showing empty rows.

Comment: my plist name is correct

Comment: Please post real code, not something you just typed in which contains typos.

Comment: See my answer and try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you converting **.plist** to dictionary in the wrong way. Check `dict` property, it should be nil. Code to create NSDictionary from .plist file is listed below:

```
CFPropertyListRef plist = CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                          (__bridge CFDataRef)propertyListData,
                                                          kCFPropertyListImmutable, NULL);
NSDictionary *settings = (__bridge NSDictionary *)plist;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
textData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Anyways, you may can take a look of this tutorial:

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-populate-a-uitableview-from-a-plist-property-list/